# Permissions user role Wordpress dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions, roles, dashboard

For my website I created a new user role but I get an error.
"You are not allowed to see this page"

```
$args = array(
    'manage_options'        => true,
    'read'                  => true,
    'publish_posts'         => true,
    'publish_pages'         => true,
    'manage_categories'     => true,
    'manage_links'          => true,
    'edit_pages'            => true,
    'edit_plugins'          => false,
    'edit_theme_options'    => false,
);

add_role( 'owner', 'eigenaar', $args );
```

I read the documentation but I can not see what is needed to get acces to the dashboard.

Who can help me with this?

Comment: you need to create Wordpress Admin user to access Dashoard. You can follow this tutorial https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/ to create Admin user. Chill

Comment: As you were writing this, did you experiment with different capabilities? If so, you might need to call `remove_role` on this role first, then re-add it. Once a role is created, things tend to get stuck.